# Cross domain cookie issue in IE

Tags: java, internet-explorer, iframe, cookies, adfs2.1

I have a web page which opens an ADFS log in form in iframe. Login form is from another domain. After successful log in ADFS will set few cookies within iframe. These cookies are required by ADFS to recognize the user log in status. 
Now, after log in when I come back to parent page and try to contact ADFS those cookies are not sent to ADFS . When I try to contact ADFS within iframe every thing works fine but once I am back on parent page somehow cookies are not sent to ADFS along with the request. 
This happens only on IE. It works fine in all other browsers.

I tried setting P3P headers but it did not resolve issue. All the cookies are httpOnly so they are not accessible through JavaScript.

Comment: Look into [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing).

Comment: I am able to get cookies in iframe but I want those cookies to be available in parent page. This is required because my log out happens from parent page. I am not sure how CORS comes into the picture in this scenario.